# Social share on confirmation page

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a way to display Facebook and Twitter share buttons/boxes on the confirmation page after the user submits a form?

I would like to encourage users to share some of the contents of their form submission on social after hitting submit. By providing some pre-populated posts for Facebook and Twitter, it would make sharing that content much easier for users.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a member of the Cognito Forms team.

At the moment, Cognito Forms does not support the ability to share entries through social media; however, we do have a similar feature on our Idea Board that you can vote for:

https://trello.com/c/CxBKsbhP/232-public-entry-views